# Image not Showing in fullscreen, Css

Tags: html, css, image, background

I tried several solutions but none worked, the image does not want to show in full screen with the same size that I specified would it be possible to have a solution in css?
Here is my code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:url(cactus2.jpg) no-repeat black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#nocursor {
    cursor: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: cant reproduce the issue with the code you provided. As a sidenote, no need for a prefix on background-size. It is supported by every browser by default.

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML-Code?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 for a background image on the body, the HTML is irrelevant unless he has an inline style applied to the body tag overwriting his CSS.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 My html code has nothing to do with the image nothing very relevant

Comment: Also is there a more revelant answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/100x50.jpg) no-repeat black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#nocursor {
  cursor: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  object-fit: center;
}
```

Comment: Not working but juste in case there is a piece of my html code that may be revelant

(im using ruffle to make the swf working)
<embed src="out.swf" height="4" width="4"></embed>
  <div id="nocursor"></div>

Comment: Plus i'm using document.requestfullscreen if its may help